# Nested JSON parser

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm novice in Swift and iOS development and can't understand something. I try to parse JSON with Alamofire to UiTableView. But JSON's response contain nested url to another JSON request. Besides this, I used MBProgressHUD for "Please wait" view. 
How I can to hide this progress view, when I processed all JSON response ?

I have next code for parse JSON.

```
func loadFileList(){

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let login = defaults.valueForKey("login") as! String
    let password = defaults.valueForKey("password") as! String

    Alamofire.request(.GET, Links.apiUrl)
        .authenticate(user: login, password: password)
        .responseJSON { response in
                    let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(response.result.value!)
                    for (_, value):(String, SwiftyJSON.JSON) in json {
                        let file: CacheFile! = CacheFile(filename: value["name"].string!, preview: value["preview"].string!, id: value["id"].string!)
                        print (file.filename)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.fileList.append(file)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })

                        Alamofire.request(.GET, file.layoutURL)
                            .authenticate(user: login, password: password)
                            .responseJSON{ responseLayout in
                                let jsonLayout = SwiftyJSON.JSON(responseLayout.result.value!)
                                let layoutsArray = jsonLayout["layouts"]
                                for (_, layoutObj):(String, SwiftyJSON.JSON) in layoutsArray{
                                    let alias = layoutObj["alias"].string!
                                    let layoutFile: Layout! = Layout(name: layoutObj["name"].string!, alias: Int(alias))
                                    print (layoutFile.name)
                                    file.addLayout(layoutFile)
                                }
                        }
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }

                    }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.hideHUD()

            }
    }

}
```

But, when HUD hided and datas showed in view, it parsed nested JSON. How to fix it?

**P.S** Or How I can do it, without Alamofire ?

Answer (score 0):

You do dismiss the HUD, when the first json is returned.

To hide the HUD, when all JSON returned you just need to rearrange your code a bit:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, Links.apiUrl)
        .authenticate(user: login, password: password)
        .responseJSON { response in
                    let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(response.result.value!)
                    for (_, value):(String, SwiftyJSON.JSON) in json {
                        let file: CacheFile! = CacheFile(filename: value["name"].string!, preview: value["preview"].string!, id: value["id"].string!)
                        print (file.filename)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.fileList.append(file)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })

                        Alamofire.request(.GET, file.layoutURL)
                            .authenticate(user: login, password: password)
                            .responseJSON{ responseLayout in
                                let jsonLayout = SwiftyJSON.JSON(responseLayout.result.value!)
                                let layoutsArray = jsonLayout["layouts"]
                                for (_, layoutObj):(String, SwiftyJSON.JSON) in layoutsArray{
                                    let alias = layoutObj["alias"].string!
                                    let layoutFile: Layout! = Layout(name: layoutObj["name"].string!, alias: Int(alias))
                                    print (layoutFile.name)
                                    file.addLayout(layoutFile)
                                }
                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                  self.hideHUD()
                                 self.tableView.reloadData()

                                }
                           }
                      }
    }
```

Basicly, you need to wrap the self.hideHUD call in the completion header of the second JSON call.

Comment: But why ? My responses are JSON array, Why i must hide HUD after complete parse nested JSON of first outer JSON ? For example, i have 5 items in response of first request and 5 in nested. I must hide HUD after first element of first request and 5 items of it ? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: You want to dismiss the HUD, when all your data is returned right? I mean that was the original question. Or what is your main problem?

Comment: Yes, You are right. But when HUD is dismissed, I saw names of nested request in console.  So it should be?

Comment: print (layoutFile.name)

This is why you see that in the console. That is fine.

Comment: it's doesn't help me. http://i.imgur.com/eKfO2P4.jpg see it. I click on file fast, when HUD was hided.

Comment: and you want see on your tableView what is written in the console?

Comment: In table view, i added CacheFile, that contain array of Layouts object. On click item in tableview, i get AllertController with Layouts of CacheFile.